# Matplotlib automate placement of watermark

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a function to automate the placement of watermark in the lower right of my figures. Here is my function so far.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def watermark(fig, ax):

    """ Place watermark in bottom right of figure. """

    # Get the pixel dimensions of the figure
    width, height = fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi

    # Import logo and scale accordingly
    img = Image.open('logo.png')
    wm_width = int(width/4) # make the watermark 1/4 of the figure size
    scaling = (wm_width / float(img.size[0]))
    wm_height = int(float(img.size[1])*float(scaling))
    img = img.resize((wm_width, wm_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Place the watermark in the lower right of the figure
    xpos = ax.transAxes.transform((0.7,0))[0]
    ypos = ax.transAxes.transform((0.7,0))[1]
    plt.figimage(img, xpos, ypos, alpha=.25, zorder=1)
```

The problem is that when I add a label to either axis the position of the water mark changes. E.g. adding `ax.set_xlabel('x-label', rotation=45)` changes the watermark position significantly. This seems to be the case because the placement of the watermark is relative to the whole figure (e.g. the plotting and axis area), however the function get_size_inches() only calculates the plotting area (e.g. not including the axis area).

Is there anyway to get the pixel dimensions of the entire figure (e.g. including axis area) or another easy workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to use an `AnchoredOffsetbox` in which you place an `OffsetImage`. The advantage would be that you can use the `loc=4` argument to place the Offsetbox in the lower right corner of the axes (just like in the case of a legend).

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import ( OffsetImage,AnchoredOffsetbox)


def watermark2(ax):
    img = Image.open('house.png')
    width, height = ax.figure.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi
    wm_width = int(width/4) # make the watermark 1/4 of the figure size
    scaling = (wm_width / float(img.size[0]))
    wm_height = int(float(img.size[1])*float(scaling))
    img = img.resize((wm_width, wm_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=1, alpha=0.2)
    imagebox.image.axes = ax

    ao = AnchoredOffsetbox(4, pad=0.01, borderpad=0, child=imagebox)
    ao.patch.set_alpha(0)
    ax.add_artist(ao)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,3,4.5,5])

watermark2(ax)
ax.set_xlabel("some xlabel")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! If you want one watermark per subplot, scale the image relative to the subplot size, i.e. ``width = ax.bbox.xmax - ax.bbox.xmin``

Comment: @Funkensieper If you want to have the watermark fill the complete axes, you can just use an `ax.imshow` plot of the image and set the zorder and alpha to your liking.

Comment: No I want the watermarks to be 1/4 of each subplot :)

Comment: Ok then I misunderstood your comment.