# Watermark image with text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a watermark image on a plot, something like is done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43844704/174944) answer, but also to add some text at the bottom of the watermark image.

I can't just put the text as part of the image, as it changes from time to time.

```
img = mpimg.imread('/path/to/image.png')
imagebox = OffsetImage(img, alpha=0.5)
ao = AnchoredOffsetbox('lower left', pad=0, borderpad=1, child=imagebox)        
ax.add_artist(ao)
```

There is no way to add another Artist to the AnchoredOffsetbox, as in can have only a [single child](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/offsetbox_api.html?#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox).

Is there any way of adding text to that image, or is there another container I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: What's stopping you from using another AnchoredOffsetbox ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I would like to have it all in the same box, within the same border. If I do it in separate boxes, I will have to fit them exactly by coordinates, and that might break if any change is done to the big figure

Comment: You can hard code the concept without hard coding the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/offsetbox_api.html?#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox), if you want several children in an `AnchoredOffsetbox` , you have the option of using a container box (`VPacker`, `HPacker`):

> When multiple children is needed, use other OffsetBox class to enclose them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import (OffsetImage, TextArea, AnchoredOffsetbox, VPacker)


def create_watermark(imagePath, label, ax=None, alpha=0.5):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    img = plt.imread(imagePath)
    imagebox = OffsetImage(img, alpha=alpha, zoom=0.2)
    textbox = TextArea(label, textprops=dict(alpha=alpha))
    packer = VPacker(children=[imagebox, textbox], mode='fixed', pad=0, sep=0, align='center')
    ao = AnchoredOffsetbox('lower left', pad=0, borderpad=1, child=packer)
    ax.add_artist(ao)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
    create_watermark('../lena.png', 'WATERMARK', ax=ax0)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`plt.text(x, y, s)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) is enough. With `x` being the coodinate of your x-axis and `y` the coordinate of your y-axis. `s` is the string you want to write to your plot.

```py
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import ( OffsetImage,AnchoredOffsetbox)


def watermark2(ax):
    img = Image.open('stinkbug.png')
    width, height = ax.figure.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi
    wm_width = int(width/4) # make the watermark 1/4 of the figure size
    scaling = (wm_width / float(img.size[0]))
    wm_height = int(float(img.size[1])*float(scaling))
    img = img.resize((wm_width, wm_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=1, alpha=0.2)
    imagebox.image.axes = ax

    ao = AnchoredOffsetbox(4, pad=0.01, borderpad=0, child=imagebox)
    ao.patch.set_alpha(0)
    ax.add_artist(ao)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,3,4.5,5])

watermark2(ax)

plt.text(3.7, 1.0, "text example")

ax.set_xlabel("some xlabel")
plt.show()
```

[image]