# Python 3 matplotlib add a watermark with multiple scale axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

In python 3, i am trying to add watermark with multiple scale axis in the following pandas data frame

```
index,as_of_date,Total_10bn,close
0,2020-08-05,620.55975367473,332.11
1,2020-08-12,621.9414641848599,337.44
2,2020-08-19,628.88298116372,337.23
3,2020-08-26,627.26943375402,347.57
4,2020-09-02,630.01703674403,357.7
5,2020-09-09,630.70673674269,339.79
6,2020-09-16,637.50390815142,338.82
```

I can make the multiple scale works

```
df_soma_spy=pd.read_csv('df_soma_spy.csv')

print(df_soma_spy)

# create figure and axis objects with subplots()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

ax.plot(df_soma_spy.as_of_date, df_soma_spy.Total_10bn, color="red") ## , marker="o"

# set x-axis label

ax.set_xlabel("Date", fontsize=12)

# set y-axis label

ax.set_ylabel("Fed SOMA ($10bn)",color="red",fontsize=14)

plt.grid(True, axis='both', which='both')

# twin object for two different y-axis on the sample plot

ax2=ax.twinx()

# make a plot with different y-axis using second axis object

ax2.plot(df_soma_spy.as_of_date, df_soma_spy["close"], color="black") ## , marker="o"

ax2.set_ylabel("$SPY Price",color="black",fontsize=14)


plt.title('Federal Reserves SOMA Total vs $SPY')

plt.show()

# save the plot as a file
fig.savefig('soma_spy.png',
            format='jpeg',
            dpi=300,
            bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Now I am trying to add a logo behind the picture. But no matter how I try, it will mess up one of the axis.

For example

```
import matplotlib.image as image

im = image.imread('xxx.png')

myaximage = ax.imshow(im, aspect='auto', extent=(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), alpha=0.5, zorder=-1)
```

In this case, the logo doesn't show up and the red axis is totally messed up.

[image]

There are some other solutions but none of them seems to work.

[Scale image in matplotlib without changing the axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742111/scale-image-in-matplotlib-without-changing-the-axis)

[Matplotlib automate placement of watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842567/matplotlib-automate-placement-of-watermark)

[Scale image in matplotlib without changing the axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742111/scale-image-in-matplotlib-without-changing-the-axis)

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ax.imshow(), you can use fig.figimage() as shown below and described [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/05/10-matplotlib-tricks-data-visualization-python/). Just insert the following two lines in your code:

```
logo = image.imread(fname='logo.png')
fig.figimage(logo,alpha= 0.1)
```

Using the partial data you provided, here is the saved image:

[image]

Comment: perfect and simple solution! I am trying to move the water mark to upper left. Playing with several parameters but none of them seem to work. Any tip? Thank you! https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figimage.html

Comment: wow you are a neuron surgeon @pakpe ! so talented!

Comment: Thanks. You can play around with the figimage arguments, but they are cumbersome and the offset only shows on the displayed image and not the saved image. Probably the best way to achieve a precise result is to pre-process your image. For instance, use Photoshop to position the water mark on the desired location on a canvas that is the same size and resolution as your saved figure.